# How to create a stored procedure in MySQL with Knex raw

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, knex.js

I am using Adonis which uses Knex under the hood. I am want to create this stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentdate DATE;
    SET currentdate = startdate;
    WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
        INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
                        YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
                        currentdate,
                        YEAR(currentdate),
                        MONTH(currentdate),
                        DAY(currentdate),
                        QUARTER(currentdate),
                        WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
                        'f',
                        CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END,
                        NULL);
        SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

TRUNCATE TABLE time_dimension;

CALL fill_date_dimension('2018-01-01','2030-12-31');
OPTIMIZE TABLE time_dimension;
```

The problem is that knex raw, or may be Adonis (I don't know) strips out the line breaks. This gives me the error

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension; DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE) BEGIN DECLARE currentdate DATE; SET currentdate = startdate; WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO INSERT INTO dates VALUES ( YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate), currentdate, YEAR(currentdate), MONTH(currentdate), DAY(currentdate), QUARTER(currentdate), WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate), DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'), DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'), 'f', CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END, NULL); SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY); END WHILE; END // DELIMITER ; TRUNCATE TABLE dates; CALL fill_date_dimension('2018-01-01','2030-12-31'); OPTIMIZE TABLE time_dimension; - ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN sto' at line 4
```

I have tried putting my own `\n` tags into the SQL, but they are stripped out.

Any idea who to make knex.raw run what I give it, rather than taking out the tags.

Answer (score 1):

This should help. Here I wrote a module expected by knex-migrate. It should be no trouble to adapt to your need.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const {
  database: {
    connection: {
      host, user, password, database, port
    }
  }
} = require('./settings.js');

exports.up = async () => {
  const script = `
    CREATE DEFINER=\`<YOUR_DB_USER>\`@\`%\` PROCEDURE \`fill_date_dimension\`(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE currentdate DATE;
        SET currentdate = startdate;
        WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
        INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
                        YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
                        currentdate,
                        YEAR(currentdate),
                        MONTH(currentdate),
                        DAY(currentdate),
                        QUARTER(currentdate),
                        WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
                        'f',
                        CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END,
                        NULL);
        SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        END WHILE;
    END`

  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host,
    user,
    database,
    password,
    port
  });

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    connection.query(
      script,
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        return resolve();
      }
    );
  });
};

exports.down = async knex => knex.raw('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension');
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the problem is not related to the client, but to the database engine which cannot accept multiple commands on one line.

In the end, I found a different way of doing the same thing without using a procedure, but I had to execute each line of code as a separate command like so.

```
await db.raw(`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS numbers_small;`)
    await db.raw(`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS numbers_small;`)
    await db.raw(`CREATE TABLE numbers_small (number INT);`)
    await db.raw(`INSERT INTO numbers_small VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);`)
    await db.raw(`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS numbers;`)
    await db.raw(`CREATE TABLE numbers (number BIGINT);`)
    await db.raw(`INSERT INTO numbers
    SELECT thousands.number * 1000 + hundreds.number * 100 + tens.number * 10 + ones.number
      FROM numbers_small thousands, numbers_small hundreds, numbers_small tens, numbers_small ones
    LIMIT 1000000;`)
    await db.raw(`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dates;`)
    await db.raw(`CREATE TABLE dates (
      date_id          BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, 
      date             DATE NOT NULL,
      timestamp        BIGINT, 
      weekend          CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT "Weekday",
      day_of_week      CHAR(10),
      month            CHAR(10),
      month_day        INT, 
      year             INT,
      week_starting_monday CHAR(2),
      UNIQUE KEY date (date),
      KEY year_week (year,week_starting_monday)
    );`)
    await db.raw(`INSERT INTO dates (date_id, date)
    SELECT number, DATE_ADD( '2016-01-01', INTERVAL number DAY )
      FROM numbers
      WHERE DATE_ADD( '2016-01-01', INTERVAL number DAY ) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2030-01-01'
      ORDER BY number;`)
    await db.raw(`UPDATE dates SET
    timestamp =   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date),
    day_of_week = DATE_FORMAT( date, "%W" ),
    weekend =     IF( DATE_FORMAT( date, "%W" ) IN ('Saturday','Sunday'), 'Weekend', 'Weekday'),
    month =       DATE_FORMAT( date, "%M"),
    year =        DATE_FORMAT( date, "%Y" ),
    month_day =   DATE_FORMAT( date, "%d" );`)
    await db.raw(`UPDATE dates SET week_starting_monday = DATE_FORMAT(date,'%v');`)
```

Comment: I'm just curious, is it for "security"? If so, what happens if you add "\n" or "\r\n" to your query?

Answer (score 0):

Simply break it into 2 [raw()](https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html#raw-queries) calls.

First with the `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;`.
Second with `CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(...` without the leading or ending `DELIMITER //` parts.

Then you can execute the rest as usual.

My similar scenario runs fine with knex v2.2.